# Ruby on Rails - possible to "group by"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement, ruby-on-rails-3.1

What I have is 3 collections of objects and 2 associations. My objects are "Owner", "Jockey" and "Horse", and the associations are OwnerID(Owner)->OwnerID(Jockey) and JockeyID(Jockey) -> JockeyID(Horse).

```
Owner
Name   **OwnerID**

Jockey
Name   **OwnerID**   *JockeyID*

Horse
Name   OwnerID   *JockeyID*
```

Each owner can have many jockeys, each jockey can have many horses. ** and * to represent key mappings.

So on the page for my "Owner", I would like to print all "Horses", but group them according to their "Jockey". I have printed them like so, without this grouping :

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>JockeyID</th>
</tr>

  <% @subject.FirstAssociation.SecondAssociation.each do |horse| %>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <%= horse['Name'].first %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= horse['JockeyID'].first %>
  </td>
  </tr>
   <% end %>
```

This will simply print :

```
Name   JockeyID
Horse     1
Horsie2   2
Horsie3   3
...
```

What I would like is to now group by jockey and instead print :

```
Jockey Name : Mark the Jockey
Name   JockeyID
Horse   1

JockeyName : Fred the Jockey
Name   JockeyID
Horsie2   2
Horsie3   3

etc.
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Are your association fields actually called `JockeyID` and `OwnerID` instead of the conventional `jockey_id` and `owner_id`?  And is the primary key in Owner `OwnerID` instead of the conventional `id`?  This feels like one of those questions where the author uses "example" fields/methods instead of their real code and ends up confusing everyone.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Sorry, I am new to Ruby and so didn't know of these conventions. Thanks for letting me know. Yes, you are correct in both cases.

Comment: Can you please edit and rewrite your question with your actual code and associations, then?  Otherwise it's going to get very confusing.

Comment: BTW i don't know how you could possibly start using Rails without knowing about association field names - that must be the first thing you learn!?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I mean to say that you are correct JockeyID and OwnerID are the association fields and OwnerID is a primary key. This is my actual code :) And I have been a Java developer for years - I don't really need to learn Ruby, just to get this aspect of the code working and move on :). Thanks for your help

Comment: ah, i see.  I'd argue that you kinda need to learn Ruby (and Rails, they're not the same thing). Anyway i'll have a go at answering.

Comment: It would be good if you can put down actual rails association and bit code of models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined association in your models like this:

```
/app/models/

Owner
 has_many :jockeys

Jockey
 belongs_to :owner
 has_many :horses

Horse
 belongs_to :owner
 belongs_to :jockey
```

If you are trying to print all the jockeys list on basis of `@owner`. you should do like this:

```
<% @owner.jockeys.each do |jockey| %>
 <tr>
  <td>Jockey Name </td>
  <td>
    <%= jockey.name %>
  </td>
  <% jockey.horses.each do |horse| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Horse Name
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= horse.name %>
      </td>
    </tr>   
<% end %>
```

you can make the necessary changes, as I write code on the basis of my assumptions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `@subject.FirstAssociation.SecondAssociation` is confusing so i'm just going to treat it as a mistake and ignore it.

Normally one would do something like this:

```
#in controller (show action, eg for url /owners/123)
@owner = Owner.find_by_id(params[:id], :include => {:jockeys => [:horses]}) 
#OR, depending on your rails version (the following is newer syntax)
@owner = Owner.where(:id => params[:id]).includes(jockeys: [:horses]).first

#in view
#doing one table per jockey here, it's not clear what's required
<% @owner.jockeys.each do |jockey| %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th><%= jockey.name %></th>
      <th><%= jockey.id %></th>
    </tr>

    <% jockey.horses.each do |horse| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%= horse.name %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= horse.JockeyId %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
<% end %>
```